# How to check on FTP if there files on the list older than 7 days

Tags: bash

I have a list of files from remote FTP Server:

```
drwxrwxrwx   2 test-backup everyone     4096 Jul  8 02:30 .
drwxrwxrwx   5 0        0            4096 Jul 23 07:02 ..
-rw-rw-rw-   1 test-backup everyone   352696 Jul 18 02:30 expdp_TEST11P2_custom_Fri.dmp.gz
-rw-rw-rw-   1 test-backup everyone   352796 Jul 21 02:30 expdp_TEST11P2_custom_Mon.dmp.gz
-rw-rw-rw-   1 test-backup everyone   352615 Jul 19 02:30 expdp_TEST11P2_custom_Sat.dmp.gz
-rw-rw-rw-   1 test-backup everyone   352626 Jul 20 02:30 expdp_TEST11P2_custom_Sun.dmp.gz
-rw-rw-rw-   1 test-backup everyone 10511523642 Jul 24 03:08 expdp_TEST11P2_custom_Thu.dmp.gz
-rw-rw-rw-   1 test-backup everyone 10496881744 Jul 22 03:03 expdp_TEST11P2_custom_Tue.dmp.gz
-rw-rw-rw-   1 test-backup everyone 10504557195 Jul 23 03:03 expdp_TEST11P2_custom_Wed.dmp.gz
```

I need to check if there are any files older than 7 days, Have You any Ideas how can I do this in Bash?

Comment: Try `man find` /15chars

Comment: I would use awk to isolate "Jul 18 02:30", date to convert that to unix time, and then subtract current unix time by file unix time and compare that difference to the number of seconds in 7 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the issue, you have a list of file list received via `ftp` (and you do not have access to `find` on the remote server).  Assuming that you have the directory list stored in a file called `ftptimes`, then you can identify files older than 7 days via:

```
$ awk -v cutoff="$(date -d "7 days ago" +%s)" '{line=$0; "date -d \""$6" " $7" " $8 "\" +%s" |getline; fdate=$1} fdate < cutoff {print line} ' ftptimes
```

From your sample date, the output would be:

```
drwxrwxrwx   2 test-backup everyone     4096 Jul  8 02:30 .
```

Addressing the parts of the `awk` command, one by one:

- -v cutoff="$(date -d "7 days ago" +%s)"

  This defines an `awk` variable called `cutoff` that will have the Unix time (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) corresponding to seven days ago
- `line=$0;`

  This saves for later use the current input line into the variable `line`.
- `"date -d \""$6" " $7" " $8 "\" +%s" |getline; fdate=$1`

  This converts the date given by ftp into Unix time, reads that time in, and saves it in a variable called `fdate`.
- `fdate < cutoff {print line}`

  If the file date is less than the cutoff date, then the line is printed.

In the sample data that you provided, the only file older than seven days is the current directory (`.`) which dates to Jul 8.

As an example, if we wanted files *older than 5 days*, then more files would be printed:

```
$ awk -v cutoff="$(date -d "5 days ago" +%s)" '{line=$0; "date -d \""$6" " $7" " $8 "\" +%s" |getline; fdate=$1} fdate < cutoff {print line} ' ftptimes
drwxrwxrwx   2 test-backup everyone     4096 Jul  8 02:30 .
-rw-rw-rw-   1 test-backup everyone   352696 Jul 18 02:30 expdp_TEST11P2_custom_Fri.dmp.gz
-rw-rw-rw-   1 test-backup everyone   352615 Jul 19 02:30 expdp_TEST11P2_custom_Sat.dmp.gz
```

In the above, I assumed that the info from ftp was stored in a file.  It is also possible to pipe it in:

```
 echo ls | ftp host port | awk -v cutoff="$(date -d "5 days ago" +%s)" '{line=$0; "date -d \""$6" " $7" " $8 "\" +%s" |getline; fdate=$1} fdate < cutoff {print line} '
```

where `host` and `port` are replaced by the host and port of your server.

#### Bash version

The above can also be accomplished in `bash` although it requires explicit looping.  Again, assuming the ftp information in the file `ftptimes`:

```
$ cutoff="$(date -d "7 days ago" +%s)"; while read line; do  set -- $line; fdate=$(date -d "$6 $7 $8" +%s) ; [ $fdate -lt $cutoff ] && echo $line ; done <ftptimes
drwxrwxrwx 2 test-backup everyone 4096 Jul 8 02:30 .
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer, but I have one more question:
In This script current year is hard-coded `"date -d \""$6" " $7" " $8 " 2014\"` is it possible to make it more universal?

Comment: @GrzegorzArturGórski I just checked it again and `date` will in fact choose a reasonable year if no year was given.  So, I removed all the hard-coded 2014s.

Answer (score -1):

The `find` command is the most flexible for date ranges. You have 3 basic tests to choose from: `-atime +n` (last access time was greater than n*24 hours ago); `-ctime +n` (file status changed greater than n*24 hours ago); and `-mtime +n` (file was modified greater than n*24 hours ago). Note: the use of `n` means exactly `n*24 hours ago`; `+n` means `greater than n*24 hours ago` and `-n` means `less than n*24 hours ago`. Also note that any fractional parts of the 24 hour period are ignored which means you may have to adjust the `+n` to `+6` to get all files `greater than 6 days old` (meaning 7 days old) rather than `+7`. Example:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +6
```

Will find all `files` (not dirs) in `/path/to/files` that were modified greater than 6 days ago (which is 7 days). You can test with `-atime`, `-ctime`, and `-mtime` to see which fits your needs.

Comment: hi, Thanks for Yours answer, but I don't have files only, list of files from external ftp server.

Comment: Your original question asked how to find files older than 7 days in BASH. I apologize for the misunderstanding about you not having shell access to the files on the ftp site. In that case, then awk is your answer as John provided. Good luck.